# Notify me when log table contains error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using `log4net` and would like to set up a process to notify me when a record is written to the `Log` table.  I would want it to run every hour or so.  I would probably use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Log 
WHERE Level = 'ERROR' 
AND Datediff(hh,[Date],getdate()) < 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [SQL Server Agent job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (I assume you're not using SQL Server Express). You will need to [set up Database Mail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/dd939167.aspx). Then you can simply schedule a job that runs every hour that says:

```
IF EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[Log] 
    WHERE Level = 'ERROR' 
    AND [Date] >= DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
)
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ...
END
```

Note that this science isn't exact... if the job starts a few seconds after 8:00 it might miss an error that occurred at 7:00:01, and if you add a few seconds' buffer, you might double-report an error that happened at 6:59:59.997. What you can consider doing to alleviate this is to store the last error you recorded somewhere, then you can add an additional `WHERE` clause:

```
AND [Date] > (SELECT MAX(LastError) FROM dbo.LastErrorLog)
```

Comment: I wonder if a trigger on the table would be a better way to go?

Comment: Then you'll get an e-mail for every single error that gets logged, instead of 1 or 0 every hour. If that's what you want, then yes it is, but that's not what you asked for.